# Plotting with Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have this input data, I want to plot with gnuplot.

```
01-02-18      456
01-05-18      438
01-06-18      451
01-09-18      458
```

How call gnuplot?

Comment: What is desired output? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i finally want to plot a graph with time on y and dates on x axis. i have dried to use awk but to no effect. I am very new to bash.
The output could be like converting the time into seconds and dates will remain as it is. And the shift the data to excel to finally plot it.

Comment: @RupankPahuja - You can use `gnuplot`, for some nice graphs. It can do simple and complex things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your expected output is:

```
date(mm-dd-yy) time(in s since midnight)
```

If I am correct you can use:

```
paste <(awk '{print $1}' dump.run) <(awk '{print $3}' dump.run | awk -F ':' '{print 3600*$1+60*$2+$3}')
```

Output:

```
02-02-18    448.932
02-03-18    445.523
02-04-18    443.869
02-05-18    446.106
```

Comment: Yeah I just nailed it myself. Thanks for the input though. Now I am on how to plot it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is no need for any perl/awk preprocessing in this case. Gnuplot can handle inputs like this natively, you just have to specify the correct `timefmt`:

```
$DATA <<EOD
01-02-18      456
01-05-18      438
01-06-18      451
01-09-18      458
EOD

set xdata time
set timefmt '%d-%m-%y'
set format x '%d-%m-%y'

plot $DATA u 1:2 w lp
```

Comment: I used excel. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

## This is a job for [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) (I think;)

```
perl -pe 's/^([0-9-]+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\.(\d+)/sprintf("%s %d.%d", $1, $2*86400+$3*3600+$4*60+$5, $6)/e;' <dump.run
02-02-18 448.932
02-03-18 445.523
02-04-18 443.869
02-05-18 446.106
```

Or

```
perl -pe 's/
    ^([0-9-]+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\.(\d+)
/
    sprintf("%s %d.%d", $1, $2*86400+$3*3600+$4*60+$5, $6)
/ex;' <dump.run
```

With a `x` modifier in perl regex, to be able to split them.

```
02-02-18 448.932
02-03-18 445.523
02-04-18 443.869
02-05-18 446.106
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `awk` and `gnuplot`, you can use this script:

```
awk '{print $1,substr($3,1,2)*3600+substr($3,4,2)*60+substr($3,7)}' file | gnuplot -e 'set xdata time; set timefmt "%m-%d-%y"; plot "/dev/stdin" using 1:2 with lines'
```

The `awk` script converts the third column of the input file into seconds.

The resulting data (day, number of seconds) is passed to gnuplot for displaying. The X axis is set as a date with the parameters `xdata`, and the format is set with `timefmt`.